# Null and blank values

Tags: c#, .net, robustness

What's the best way of writing robust code so that a variable can be checked for null and blank.

e.g.

```
string a;

if((a != null) && (a.Length() > 0))
{
    //do some thing with a
}
```

Comment: Where did you hear of C#.Net? There is no such thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For strings, there is

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(a))
```

Comment: Better use String.IsNullOrEmpty()

Comment: `string` beats `String` because you don't have to press shift, making your keyboard last longer, and makes you less tired, plus you don't need a `using System;` for the lowercase version. (kidding, applied and +1 for the correct capitalization when clearly accessing a static class method)

Answer (score 3):

You can define an extension method to allow you to do this on many things:

```
static public bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable <T>input)
{
    return input == null || input.Count() == 0;
}
```

It already exists as a static method on the `System.String` class for strings, as has been pointed out.

Comment: quoting John Skeet:
However, you should definitely use Any(). That way it only needs to test for the presence of the first element. This will be incredibly cheap for normal implementations of ICollection<T>, but could be *much* faster than Count() for cases involving a complex query.

http://danielvaughan.orpius.com/post/IEnumerable-IsNullOrEmpty.aspx

Answer (score 3):

And if you are using .NET 4.0 you might want to take a look at [String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

From version 2.0 you can use [IsNullOrEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx).

```
string a;
...
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(a)) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

for strings:

```
string a;
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(a))
{
//do something with a
}
```

for specific types you could create an extention method 
note that i've used HasValue instead of IsNullorEmpty because 99% of the times you will have to use the !-operator if you use IsNullOrEmpty which I find quite unreadable

```
public static bool HasValue(this MyType value)
{
//do some testing to see if your specific type is considered filled
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(string name))
{
   ///  write ur code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find Apache Commons.Lang StringUtils (Java)'s naming a lot easier: isEmpty() checks for null or empty string, isBlank() checks for null, empty string, or whitespace-only. isNullOrEmpty might be more descriptive, but empty and null is, in most cases you use it, the same thing.